# Powershell- Can't reference variable when making a file and setting its name with New-Item

Tags: variables, powershell

Code:

```
$date = (Join-path C:\Users\<username>\Desktop\ (Get-Date).toString())
New-Item -Path c:\Users\<username>\Desktop -Name "" + $((Get-Date).toString()) + ".txt" -ItemType file
$reader = [System.IO.File]::OpenText("C:\Users\<username>\Desktop\test.csv")
try {
    for(;;) {
        $line = $reader.ReadLine()
        if ($line -eq $null) { break }
        # process the line
    Add-Content "C:\Users\<username>\Desktop\"($date.txt) -value $line
        $line
    }
}
finally {
    $reader.Close()
}
```

I've tried it a dozen different ways, but I'm not sure how to do it. I'm trying to make a file with the date included as part of the name (for documentation, as I will be doing it several times regularly), and process each line of the file to be altered and put into the new file. Anyone know how to get this to work?

**EDIT:** Ok so I got it to read through, and it almost works. Unfortunately, i don't think I am calling the objects right.

My code:

```
$fileName = '{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss}.html' -f (Get-Date)
New-Item $fileName -itemtype file
Add-content $fileName "<html>"
Add-content $fileName "<head>"
Add-content $fileName "    <title>Call Logs</title>"
Add-content $fileName "<head>"
Add-content $fileName "<body>"
Add-content $fileName "    <div id='header'>"
Add-content $fileName "    </div>"
Add-content $fileName "    <div id='table'>"
Add-content $fileName "        </table>"
Add-content $fileName "        <tr>"
Add-content $fileName "            <th>Date</th>"
Add-content $fileName "            <th>Time</th>"
Add-content $fileName "            <th>Call Type</th>"
Add-content $fileName "            <th>Calling Number</th>"
Add-content $fileName "            <th>Calling Extension</th>"
Add-content $fileName "            <th>Calling Department</th>"
Add-content $fileName "            <th>Called Number</th>"
Add-content $fileName "            <th>Called Extension</th>"
Add-content $fileName "            <th>Called Department</th>"
Add-content $fileName "            <th>Call Connected</th>"
Add-content $fileName "            <th>Duration</th>"
Add-content $fileName "            <th>Queuing Time</th>"
Add-content $fileName "            <th>Account Code</th>"
Add-content $fileName "            <th>Carrier Code</th>"
Add-content $fileName "        </tr>"

import-csv -path 'C:\users\<username>\Desktop\test.csv' |
    foreach-object{
    $newRow = "        <tr><td>$_.Date</td><td>$_.Time</td><td>$_.'Call Type'</td><td>$_.'Calling Number'</td><td>$_.'Calling Extension'</td><td>$_.'Calling Department'</td><td>$_.'Called Number'</td><td>$_.'Called Extension'</td><td>$_.'Called Department'</td><td>$_.'Call Connected'</td><td>$_.Duration</td><td>$_.'Queuing Time'</td><td>$_.'Account Code'</td><td>$_.'Carrier Code'</td></tr>"
        return $newRow

    } |
    Add-content $fileName
```

Now I get, with each call to $*.Whatever, everything. For example when I call $*.Date, I get

```
@{Date=7/1/2012; Time=16:43:06; Call Type=Terminating; Calling Number=XXXXXXXXXX; Calling Extension=; Calling Department=; Called Number=YYYYYYYYYY; Called Extension=XXXX; Called Department=Sales Engineers; Call Connected=No; Duration=0:00:11; Queuing Time=; Account Code=; Carrier Code=}.Date
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `(Get-Date).ToString()` in file names, as it's likely to contain invalid/problematic characters (e.g. `/` or `:`). Better use a defined format: `(Get-Date -f 'yyyy-MM-dd HH.mm.ss')`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't say what isn't working, so here are some generic suggestions.  If you can post any error messages, or specific things that aren't working, I can be more specific.

As a commenter stated, `(Get-Date).ToString()` returns something like `7/10/2013 7:38:22 AM`, which may or may not work in a filename.  You'll want to format it so that you know it will work in a filename, e.g. `$fileName = '{0:yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss}.txt' -f (Get-Date)`.

Second, PowerShell has an [Import-Csv](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176874.aspx) function which will read a CSV file and turn it into objects.  You can then process each object, which will have properties for each column of the CSV, returning a string that you want in your destination file.

Here is an updated script:

```
$fileName = '{0:yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss}.txt' -f (Get-Date)
$outputFile = Join-Path 'C:\Users\<username>\Desktop' $filename
New-Item $outputFile -ItemType File
Import-Csv -Path 'C:\Users\<username>\Desktop\test.csv' |
    ForEach-Object { 
        "        <tr><td>{0}</td><td>{1}</td><td>{2}</td><td>{3}</td><td>{4}</td><td>{5}</td><td>{6}</td><td>{7}</td><td>{8}</td><td>{9}</td><td>{10}</td><td>{11}</td><td>{12}</td><td>{13}</td></tr>" -f `
            $_.Date,$_.Time,$_.'Call Type',$_.'Calling Number',$_.'Calling Extension',$_.'Calling Department',$_.'Called Number',$_.'Called Extension',$_.'Called Department',$_.'Call Connected',$_.Duration,$_.'Queuing Time',$_.'Account Code',$_.'Carrier Code'
    } |
    Add-Content $outputFile
```

Comment: ok. that makes sense, but how do i manipulate each column as they come in?

Comment: What are the columns in your CSV? The `ForEach-Object` cmdlet will receive an object with properties that match the column names, e.g. `$_.Column1`.

Comment: some of them are simple like "Date" but what about when it is something like "Caller Name"?

Comment: Quote the property name in quotes, e.g. `$_.'Caller Name'`.

Comment: Thanks. It doesnt seem to be working though. I'll edit my original post to show the changes I made, and the error im having

Comment: You're not embedding the variables correctly in your table row string.  When you want to embed an object's property in a string, you have to wrap it in `$($_.Date)`, or use the format operator, e.g. `'{0}' -f $_.Date`. I updated my answer.